# String representing multiple ranges gets cut off

Tags: excel, vba

In my code, this string is truncated:

```
strRange = _
"$E$8:$E$86," & _
"$F$14:$H$17,$F$20:$H$23,$F$25:$H$28,$F$30:$H$39,$F$42:$H$46,$F$48:$H$51,$F$53:$H$55,$F$57:$H$58,$F$60:$H$68,$F$70:$H$84,$F$86:$H$86," & _
"$I$8:$I$86,$K$8:$K$86," & _
"$L$14:$P$17,$L$20:$P$23,$L$25:$P$28,$L$30:$P$39,$L$42:$P$46,$L$48:$P$51,$L$53:$P$55,$L$57:$P$58,$L$60:$P$68,$L$70:$P$84,$L$86:$P$86,$R$8:$R$86"
```

Immediate, locals and watch window show only the first ~300 characters.

The command

```
Set myRange= mySheet.Range(strRange)
```

fails with

> runtime error 91

This seems to work:

```
strRange1 = _
"$E$8:$E$86," & _
"$F$14:$H$17,$F$20:$H$23,$F$25:$H$28,$F$30:$H$39,$F$42:$H$46,$F$48:$H$51,$F$53:$H$55,$F$57:$H$58,$F$60:$H$68,$F$70:$H$84,$F$86:$H$86"

strRange2 = _
"$I$8:$I$86,$K$8:$K$86," & _
"$L$14:$P$17,$L$20:$P$23,$L$25:$P$28,$L$30:$P$39,$L$42:$P$46,$L$48:$P$51,$L$53:$P$55,$L$57:$P$58,$L$60:$P$68,$L$70:$P$84,$L$86:$P$86,$R$8:$R$86"

Set myRange= Union(mySheet.Range(strRange1), mySheet.Range(strRange2))
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: It is a limitation of only 256 characters for setting a range from such a string... How the strings in discussion have been built?

Comment: Also, you can probably get rid of the `$` signs to shorten it up quite a bit, if that helps.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I'd every use such a construct, but if push comes to shove you could split the initial string and loop each element in the resulting array:

```
For Each Rng In Split(strRange, ",")
    If myRange Is Nothing Then
        Set myRange = mySheet.Range(Rng)
    Else
        Set myRange = Union(myRange, mySheet.Range(Rng))
    End If
Next
```